# How can I develop a predictive model based on predictions from various linear regression models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

I am working on a problem at work that has presented some difficulty.  I've included a *very* generalized example to demonstrate the problem I'm dealing with.

In this case, let's say I am looking at data for several companies (companies A, B and C) from the past several years, and developing models for each that predict the sales revenue based upon an industry quality score (the only feature in consideration).  The 3 companies I've analyzed vary significantly in their size and quality scores.

The problem is that I want to use the predictions for the models I created to then be able to project what the revenue would be for Company D (currently scoring around 2), if it were to acheive a quality score of 10.

Here is the code I've used to set up the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

company_a = np.array([
    [0.8, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.5, 1.2],
    [3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2]])

company_b = np.array([
    [14.5, 15.3, 15.1, 18.7, 18.2, 19.2, 17.8, 22.0, 22.8, 24.1],
    [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])

company_c = np.array([
    [7.4, 5.6, 5.2, 6.7, 7.1, 5.9, 8.2, 7.8, 7.9, 11.2],
    [7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 10]])

company_d = np.array([[23.0],[2]])

companies = {"company_a": (company_a, "b"), "company_b": (company_b, "r"), "company_c": (company_c, "g"), "company_d": (company_d, "k")}

def plot_companies(data, clr):
    lin_reg = LinearRegression()
    X = data[1].reshape(-1, 1)
    y = data[0].reshape(-1, 1)
    try:
        lin_reg.fit(X, y)
        y_predict = lin_reg.predict(X)
        plt.plot(X, y, clr + ".")
        plt.plot(X, y_predict, clr + "-", alpha=0.3)
    except:
        plt.plot(X, y, clr + ".")

for key, value in companies.items():
    plot_companies(value[0], value[1])
plt.xlabel("Industry Quality Score", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("Revenue (millions of dollars)", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[Plot of data points and linear models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96mEW.png)

Assuming the Company D currently has a rank of 2 and has 23M in revenue, how could I use the 3 linear models for the other companies to project Company D's revenue if it were to acheive a quality score of 10?

Answer (score 0):

Your plot shows that there is no general linear relationship with revenue and quality: it depends on the company you are looking at.

So the answer is you can't say anything about a new company just knowing it's quality score.

However the relationship looks indeed roughly linear for each company individually.
By the way isn't your measure of quality taking revenues as input ? In that case that would explain straightforwardly that the regression works.

As for estimating the revenue of a new company with known quality, if you're have one point (quality, revenue)  you can just say that revenue is going to be higher when quality is 10.
If you have 2 points you can draw a line, and if you have nothing then it's not ppssible.